# Date Parameter Format Issue

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to add two Date parameters to a report.  I created a Dataset that pulls the available dates.  I formatted the field so it would appear like 01/01/2013.  However, the dropdowns include the timestamp as well and I just want to see the date.  How can I do that?

Here is the query for my Dataset.

```
SELECT
CAST(sd.SBINDT as date)
FROM dbo.SalesData sd
GROUP BY sd.SBINDT
ORDER BY sd.SBINDT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably not selecting the type of parameter, date/time, in the parameter itself.

1. Click under 'Parameters' folder in 'Report Data' section
2. Find your parameter, double click
3. Ensure 'Data type:' is 'Date/Time'.  Even though it states this the default display will be MM/DD/YYYY without the time in SSRS defaults.

You can get the values for this from a dataset, explicitly, or not list them.

Comment: I did select Date/Time.  It still displays the time in the drop down.  I just want the Date.  The field is originally datetime which is why I CAST it as Date.

Comment: Okay then let's trick the system's defaults.  Set the parameter to Text then and add this select cast( Cast(sd.SBINDT) as date) as varchar(16)).  You now should have a drop down of text instead.  When you evaluate it later you may have to cast it yet again.

Comment: That worked, but your parens were wrong.   CAST(CAST(SBINDT AS date)AS varchar(16))

Answer (score 0):

Hello I know this is old but just incase someone is looking through this may be helpful

=FORMATDATETIME(Today(),DATEFORMAT.ShortDate)

Answer (score 0):

I think, it should be like this...

**<%=FORMATDATETIME(Today(),DATEFORMAT.ShortDate)%>**